# Why does variable initialization of to an assignment expression [String x = (x = y)] compile?

Tags: java

How does this compiles without error?  As my understanding, the compiler checks the type of the variable (in this case `String`), then sees if the type of the expression on the right side corresponds to the variable's type (or at least a subtype but let's stick to the simple case with the `String` class since it's final).

```
public class InitClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = (str = "hello");
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

My question is how does `str = "hello"` compile? Is the compiler already aware that `str` should be of type `String`?

Comment: (str = "hello") returns the string "hello".  Eclipse discourage it with message: "The assignment to variable str has no effect"

Comment: @LeTex I generally set Eclipse to be stricter and report these as errors rather than warnings. I see no reason for anyone to use constructs like these even though they're allowed by the JLS.

Comment: One those interesting questions where you are left thinking "who is writing code like this and why". Purely academic, surely?

Comment: @TEK If you want to know how I got this question, it was just due to a simple copy-paste issue :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When evaluating an [assignment expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1)

> **First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable.** If
>   this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression
>   completes abruptly for the same reason; the right-hand operand is not
>   evaluated and no assignment occurs.

That produces the variable `str`. Then

> Otherwise, **the right-hand operand is evaluated**. If this evaluation
>   completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly
>   for the same reason and no assignment occurs.

In your example, the right hand operand is itself another assignment expression. So `str`, the right hand operand of the assignment operator, is again evaluated to produce a variable, `str`. Then

> Otherwise, the value of the right-hand operand is converted to the
>   type of the left-hand variable, is subjected to value set conversion
>   (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an
>   extended-exponent value set), **and the result of the conversion is
>   stored into the variable.**

So `"hello"` is stored into `str`. [And since](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of
>   the variable after the assignment has occurred. The result of an
>   assignment expression is not itself a variable.

the result of the assignment of `"hello"` to `str` is the value `"hello"`, that value is again stored in `str`.

Answer (score 5):

Your case is equivalent to

```
String str;
str = (str = "hello");
```

Although the assignments are funny looking, there's nothing wrong conceptually.

Nevertheless, a variable initialization that references itself is obviously not a good idea. The compiler will try to flag it in situations that's very likely a programer error; the compiler fails to do so some times; and may also go overboard some other times.

A local variable has a stricter requirement (than a field variable) - it must be assigned first before its value is used. For example, this won't compile, because the local var is read before it's assigned.

```
String str;  // local variable
str = str;   // error, try to read `str` before it's assigned
```

A field variable always has a default initial value; nevertheless, the compiler checks for apparent programer mistakes

```
int x = x+1;  // error. x is field variable.
```

But it's not catastrophic if such checking fails, since `x` has a value `0` before explicit assignment

```
int x;
{ x=x+1; } // ok. x==0, then x==1 after assignment
```

However, if `x` is `final`, the code above fails, because compiler requires definite assignment of `x` first before reading `x`, the same requirement for a local variable. But this checking can be circumvented, because it's impossible to analyze and prevent it fully for field variables

```
final int x = (this).x+1;  // compiles!
```

In some cases, the compiler goes overboard, preventing legit use cases involving lambda

```
Runnable r1 = ()->System.out.println(r1);  // r1 is a field variable
```

There's nothing conceptually problematic in this use case; it can be circumvented by `(this).` too.

Comment: The last part of your answer is very interesting, +1

Answer (score 0):

What first happens is that the compiler identify the type of the reference then knowing that is a String assign "hello" to str is valid.