# Instance initializer and *this* keyword

Tags: java, initialization

Trying to compile this piece of code

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        new Main();
    }

    { System.out.println(x); } //Error here

    int x=1;
}
```

produces a `cannot reference a field before it is defined` error. But if I change the initializer row to

```
    { System.out.println(this.x); }
```

it works like a charm, printing the default int value *0*.

This is a bit confusing to me, why does `this` makes the difference? Shouldn't it be redundant in this case? Can anyone explain me what happens behind the scenes to make it clear how it really works?

PS: I know that by declaring `x` before the initializer would make it work too.

Comment: `static {...}` would be the static one

Comment: as a side note: this is exactly why fields should be declared on the top of the class - to avoid such WTF moments like this one. What's funny (another WTF): it works even without `this` for **constructors** - but doesn't for **initialization blocks**. What's even more funny (IMO) - there ain't a single reasonable reason *why* the clause you provided *shouldn't* work; granted, it's a lousy way to code - but it should work OK, since the order of execution is forced (first set the initial field value, then execute the initalizer, then the c-tor).

Comment: It's interesting how frequently this question is asked, and every time it gets high votes :) see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/30838302/2158288

Comment: related - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30830384/2158288

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will try it to explain on the compiler layer.

Say you have a method like:

```
int x;
x = 1;
System.out.println(x);
```

The compilation will succed and the execution as well.
If you change the Method into this:

```
System.out.println(x);
int x;
x = 1;
```

It will not even compile the same it is with your given example.

The compiler copies the code of the `{ }` intializer into the 
`ctor` and also the `x=1` initialization.

As you said it works if you set the `x=1` before the `{ }` intializer.

```
public class MainC {

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        new MainC();
    }

    int x=1;
    {
      System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

See the following Java bytecode:

```
  public MainC();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: iconst_1
         6: putfield      #2                  // Field x:I
         9: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        12: aload_0
        13: getfield      #2                  // Field x:I
        16: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
        19: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0
        line 7: 4
        line 9: 9
        line 10: 19
```

The field `x` is declared and gets the value `1` before it is used in the
`System.out.println` call.

So why it doesn't work if you set it after the `{ }` from the same reason
you cant use the Code of my second example. The field is declared after the usage which makes no sense.

So why it works with the `this` keyword?!

Lets look us some code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        new Main();
    }

    { System.out.println(this.x); } //Error here

    int x=1;
}
```

The corresponding Java Bytecode for the ctor:

```
  public Main();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         7: aload_0
         8: getfield      #3                  // Field x:I
        11: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
        14: aload_0
        15: iconst_1
        16: putfield      #3                  // Field x:I
        19: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0
        line 7: 4
        line 9: 14
```

So whats happens here? Easy speaking the `this` keyword loads the Main object
reference on the stack. After that the field x can be accessed so the `System.out.println` call can be executed successfully.

Answer (score 5):

[JSL 8.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6) should explain your compile-time error:

> Instance initializers are permitted to refer to the current object via the keyword this (§15.8.3) ...
>
> Use of instance variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is sometimes restricted, even though these instance variables are in scope. See §8.3.3 for the precise rules governing forward reference to instance variables.

In [§8.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3), it says:

> Use of instance variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is sometimes restricted, even though these instance variables are in scope. Specifically, it is a compile-time error if **all** of the following are true:
>
> - The declaration of an instance variable in a class or interface C appears textually after a use of the instance variable;
> - The use is a **simple name** in either an instance variable initializer of C or an instance initializer of C;
> - The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.

That's why writing the simple name `x` gives you the error.

Comment: Well, that's half an answer. I was more interested in why `this` actually makes the difference.

Comment: Because `this.x` is not a simple name. It means that one of the above conditions is not true. So, no error.

Comment: Ok, so it should just be a matter of syntax, right? No new *background instances* involved?

Comment: No new background instances. Just syntax. As you've pointed out, if you declare `x` before the initializer, it doesn't matter if you write `this.x` or `x`, does it? :-)

Comment: Sure, and you can also instantiate `x` by writing `x = 1` without using `this` as well

Comment: Anyway, I don't see the need for such a restriction, I think it's just confusing. Or maybe there's some sacrosanct reason I ignore =)

Answer (score 1):

As in JSL ([§15.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3))

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword `this` denotes a value that **is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked** ([§15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)), or to the object being constructed.

`This` keyword, being called creates the instance of the class in the background then. When you call `{ System.out.println(this.x); }` variable `i` is created with `Main` class.

Comment: But then I would expect to have some kind of a loop: `this` creates an instance, then the initializer gets executed again and so on...

Comment: nope, `JVM` has a mechanism for this... if not `this` will always cause an infinite loop

Comment: So when you say *variable i is created with Main class* you mean that an object (say `i`) of class Main is created by the jvm?

Comment: Using `this` does not create an instance.

Comment: I don't see how calling `this` in an initializer block would create an instance, the initializer block is executed due to an instance being created.

Comment: `this` does *not* 'create the instance of the class in the background'.

Answer (score 0):

> Instance initializers are permitted to refer to the current object via
>   the keyword this (§15.8.3), to use the keyword super (§15.11.2,
>   §15.12), and to use any type variables in scope.
>
> Initialization consists of execution of any class variable
>   initializers and static initializers of the class Test, in textual
>   order.

What happens is that jvm allocates memory for x in the stack frame. When you use this.x 0 is returned as the variable is already allocated.
You will get 1 if the variable is static as it gets initialized.